# Чтение файла построчно

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно открыть файл и прочитать его построчно, то есть взять первую строку занести её в переменную, проделать с ней определённые операции, потом брать вторую и т.д.

Comment: Смотрите метод getline() Например:

    std::string name;
    std::getline (std::cin,name);

Answer (score 7):

вот код не вырванный из контекста

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // подключаем строки
#include <fstream> // подключаем файлы

using namespace std; // используем стандартное пространство имен

int main(){
    string s; // сюда будем класть считанные строки
    ifstream file("C:\\PriceList.dat"); // файл из которого читаем (для линукс путь будет выглядеть по другому)

    while(getline(file, s)){ // пока не достигнут конец файла класть очередную строку в переменную (s)
        cout << s << endl; // выводим на экран
        s += "+"; // что нибудь делаем со строкой например я добавляю плюсик в конце каждой строки
        cout << s << endl; // и снова вывожу на экран но уже модифицированную строку (без записи ее в файл)
    }

    file.close(); // обязательно закрываем файл что бы не повредить его

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ээээ... А вы уверены насчёт `eof`? Если я не ошибаюсь, `eof` для `istream`'ов возвращает true не когда поток находится в конце файла, а когда _поток находится в конце файла, и предыдущая попытка чтения из-за этого завершилась неудачно_.

Comment: если честно я сам не уверен, насколько я понимаю при считывании очередной строки указатель сдвигается на конец этой строки. давно не кодил но пример отлично отрабатывает без ошибок. а вот сдесь http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/11304/ тоже похожий код указан

Comment: А на пустом файле работает?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4533063/276994

Comment: да в пустом файле цикл выполняется один раз но в строку ничего не попадает

Comment: Нуууу... «Ничего» означает «`getline` отрабатывает с ошибкой, мы игнорируем ошибку и используем непонятно чем инициализированное значение `s`»?

Comment: а я это расцениваю как файл не может быть пустым там же находится указатель на его конец, значит один оборот всяко будет чтоб найти этот самый конец, а в переменную попадает NULL

Comment: А если размер файла 0, он всё равно не пустой? И как различить тогда файл с одной строчкой и с нулём? (Но вы всё же посмотрите обсуждение по ссылке.)

Comment: да я то прекрасно понял о чем вы. для системы он нулевого размера. а для его чтения нужно сделать хотя бы один такт чтобы прийти к его концу потому что указатель находится до указателя конца. вообще то я прихожу тогда к такому выводу в котором сначала надо его проверить на пустоту средствами АПИ системы, а потом переходить уже к обработке.

Comment: Ну или просто `while (getline(...))`, так же проще!

Comment: по большому счету вы правы. счас код поправлю

Comment: @Abyx вы меня отговариваете от хороших привычек ? ))

Answer (score 5):

```
ifstream file(fileName);//создаем объект потока istream  по имени file
                        // который инициализируется  именем fileName,
                       //вызывается функция file.open();
 string str;         //переменная стринг для строки                                
while(getline(file,str)) //getline(istream & is, string &s,char c='\n'),читает из потока is, в строку s пока 
{                        //не встретит символ c (без этого символа до новой строки)
                       // возвращает свой объект istream, в условии проверяется состояние iostate флагa, значение этого флага будет ложным, если достигнет конца файла, или будет ошибка ввода или читаемого типа
      fncn(str); // вызываем нужною функцию для полученной строки
}
```

Comment: А за что минус? Откомментируйте, плиз.